# Using Controllers In Directives In AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

***my directive:***

```
angular.module('matrixarMatrice', []).directive('mtxMatriceForm', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'views/matrice/matrice.html',
    scope: {
      matrix: '=',
      isclicked: '=',
      selectedprice: '&'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      ...
      scope.selected = function (prices) {
        scope.selected.id = prices.id;
        scope.selectedprice(prices);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

***my controller:***

```
$scope.selectedprice = function (prices) {
  console.log(prices);
};
```

***my html:***

```
<mtx-matrice-form matrix="matrix " isclicked="isclicked" selectedprice="selectedprice(prices)"></mtx-matrice-form>
```

In my directive when i select item i call my controller.
I want to exploit my object prices, but the problem i have at the moment is i have an `undefined` in my controller.
Does anyone know the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Shouldn't this `selectedprice="selectedprice(prices)"` be `selectedprice="selectedprice"`? Your code binds the _result_ of calling `selectedprice(prices)` to the directive's `scope.selectedprice`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found this solution:

***in my directive:***

```
...
scope.selected = function (prices) {
   scope.selected.id = prices.id;
   scope.selectedprice({prices: prices});
};
...
```

Comment: Basically, when you want to pass a function to the directive, you need to pass the parameter as an object. So in you case, it should look like this: `<mtx-matrice-form matrix="matrix " isclicked="isclicked" selectedprice="selectedprice({prices: foo})"></mtx-matrice-form>`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the one option that you can use to include controller inside a directive! There are other options as well. Hope it helps!

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Lorem';
});

app.directive('directives', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function($scope, $element){
      $scope.name = $scope.name + "impsum";
    },
    link: function(scope, el, attr) {
      scope.name = scope.name + "Ipsum";
    }
  }
})
```